# Why the famo.us/angular is no longer supported by Famo.us

Tags: angularjs, famo.us, famous-angular

I've found Famo.us when I try to make better animation on mobile devices. But as a angular developer, I still want to use ionic in my next App, so the famo.us/angular comes to me.

When I starting to research it on github, it says

> This integration library is no longer supported by Famo.us

Github link : [famous-angular](https://github.com/famous/famous-angular/)

But I can't find any more explanation about the statement.

Can anyone give me some information about that statement? Are there any risks or issues if I still use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [what happened](https://techcrunch.com/2015/11/06/nopen-source/).

It's up to you whether you use it, but my feelings would be no. To be honest I'm sure if you hunt around you'll find something much more up to date anyway.

I know a few people have success with the [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) framework, another could be [ngFX](https://github.com/AngularClass/ng-fx). Personally I've been pretty happy with Angular's native ngAnimate of late, it's definitely been improved in most recent releases. Combining this with css animation and you have everything you need.